# Generic Content Player?

Tags: communication

The general idea on the web appears to be that video/audio are to be separated with plain text. By separated, I mean you have a place that plays video/audio and a place that you read text. This is because it is widely understood that they are vastly different. However, audio and video are just another way of communication, just like text. So why do we separate the two even if they are nearly the same thing?

Correct me if I'm wrong but, most tutorials are either plain text how-to's (wiki-style) or visual/auditory instructional videos (YouTube). Why aren't the two combined?

Or, if it's already been done can someone reply with the link?

This might be bordering off-topic and if it is off-topic then please point me to the right place so it won't be.

This might also appear to be an obvious question, however I'm not sure if this subject has really been deeply thought-out by more than a few individuals.

Comment: What exactly are your asking?

Comment: Why aren't text-based how-to's and video/audio-based how'to's combined?

Comment: like sub-titles?

Comment: No, I'm saying within the content themselves, i.e a media player that's also a document reader

Comment: you mean like web browser ;)

Comment: You'll need to resolve the huge disparity between the preferred interaction modes for temporal data like audiovisual content and static information like textual content.

Comment: Let me further clarify, combining audio, video, and text in the same frame in the same format, and by combining I mean the ability to read, watch, or hear all of the three with little difference among the formats.

Comment: Now I am totally confused. How is this different than a web browser and how do you put text in the same format as video or audio?

Comment: My question was more of "Why can't you put them in the same format?", and the obvious answer is "they're different", however has it even been tried before to do that? I don't mean Text as a video or vice-versa, I mean why don't media players "play" text as well?

Comment: Well first of all, as Anon stated, text is not temporal, so what would it mean to play text.

Comment: Text is still temporal, you read left to right, right? Well when you re-read something that's not very different from going back a few seconds in a video, no?

Comment: Anon, isn't animation the solution to that? Such as http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u6XAPnuFjJc

Comment: you can not point to a specific location in textual data by using time as your reference point.

Comment: animation of text is still video

Comment: This question is confused.  It sounds like you're asking for subtitles...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few mashups may be of some use:

- You can use [flowplayer](http://flowplayer.org/index.html) to stream and/or play .flv, flash and [stream MP3's with a plugin.](http://flowplayer.org/plugins/streaming/audio.html)
- Lots of wikihow articles have videos on them
- It doesn't work very well usually, but there is transcribe audio on youtube.
- HTML 5 Canvas can embed video in it, as well as show text.